# how to integrate multiple data sources in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have one question.

I'm Sorry, if this question is too silly but i don't have any idea. How to integrate multiple data sources in hadoop. for example we are  getting the data from MYSQL so we are using Sqoop to load data into HDFS.
and we have another source which is not structured data

my questions is is there any way to integrate these 2 data sources?

Thanks in adv,

Comment: You'll have to parse and read this unstructured data *somehow* for it to be useful and joined against other data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can integrate these two sources using [bizstats.ai](https://www.bizstats.ai/) & lot of data source connectors there to integrate into one